# Obtaining the latest of a table in a view

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I am trying to create a view that takes the latest of each individual item's history and returns it in a row. The query that I want to run looks like:

```
SELECT item_pk.Id Id, item_name.Value Name 
FROM item_pk
JOIN 
(
    SELECT * FROM item_name
    ORDER BY Occurred DESC
) item_name ON item_name.Id = item_pk.Id
GROUP BY item_pk.Id
```

This query works fine and returns exactly what I want, but when I try to convert it to a view, it won't let me use subqueries. When I try:

```
CREATE VIEW item_name_latest AS SELECT * FROM item_name ORDER BY Occurred DESC;
CREATE VIEW item AS SELECT item_pk.Id Id, item_name.value Name 
FROM item_pk
JOIN item_name_latest item_name ON item_name.Id = item_pk.Id
GROUP BY item_pk.Id
```

the `item` view produces the wrong results. The results I get are exactly the same as if I had joined to `item_name` directly without the intermediate view that should produce the corrected order. Which is to say, instead of receiving the newest rows per item from `item_name`, I'm receiving the oldest. Calling the `SELECT` statement directly (rather than on the view) also produces the wrong results.

Say I have the following data:

```
Id | Value        | Occurred
1    Bob            1325697408000
1    Bobbie         1325697536000
2    Stuff          1325697822000
2    More Stuff     1325697823000
2    Latest Stuff   1325697824000
1    Roberta        1325697945000
```

The expected result (and the actual result of the given query-with-sub-query) is:

```
1    Roberta
2    Latest Stuff
```

The actual result of the view is:

```
1    Bob
2    Stuff
```

Is there a way to produce the expected values with a view, or is there a better way to obtain the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this to create your view:

```
create view item_latest as
select
  id, 
    max(occurred) as latestoccurred 
from 
    item_name 
group by
    id;

create view item as
select
    i1.id,
    i1.value
from
    item_name i1
    inner join item_latest i2 on
        i1.id = i2.id
        and i1.occurred = i2.latestoccurred;
```

It grabs only the items that have the `occurred` value of the greatest `occurred` value for that `id`.

Comment: It pointed me in the right direction. I renamed `Item` to `Item_Name_Value` and `JOIN`ed it into my `Item` table since I needed to join several of these history columns into a single view. Thanks!